# Elliptic curve with only one point

Tags: field-theory, elliptic-curves

Is there an elliptic curve $E$ over an infinite field $K$ such that $E(K)=\{\infty\}$?

My original task was to find an elliptic curve over some field $K$ with only one point, which I did for $K=\mathbb{F}_2.$ Now, I'm curious about the case of infinite cardinality, which I am not able to handle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this database](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/108/a/1), 
the elliptic curve
$$E : y^2z=x^3−108z^3$$
has only $[0:1:0]$ as rational point, i.e. $E(\Bbb Q)$ is the trivial group.
Further examples are given [here](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/?start=0&rank=0&torsion=1&torsion_structure=%5B%5D&surj_quantifier=include&count=100).

(Notice that if $K$ is an algebraically closed field (hence infinite), then $E(K)$ is always infinite, since it contains $(\Bbb Z/n \Bbb Z)^2$ for every $n \geq 1$, coprime to $\mathrm{char}(K)$ if $K$ has positive characteristic.)

---

I may add the following related and interesting result, by Mazur and Rubin (theorem 1.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.3709v3.pdf)): 
if $K$ is a number field, then there is an elliptic curve $E$ over $K$ with $E(K) = \{0\}$.

Comment: $y^2=x^3-5$ seems to work as well

Comment: If $K$ has characteristic $p$, the $p$-torsion of $E(K)$ is never $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^2$ even when $K$ is algebraically closed.